# How to use string interpolation with CultureInfo?

Tags: c#

I'm doing some testing around formatting in c#, and want to do some string interpolation while also using US CultureInfo (System.Globalization). Without string interpolation this code gives me the correct date format:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 4, 22);

CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("en-US");

Console.WriteLine("Choosen date is: " + date.ToString("d", provider));
```

This will display the date on US format:
*Choosen date is: 4/22/2013*

How can I do this when using string interpolation? Here are one of my failed attempts, using String.Format:

```
CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("en-US");

Console.WriteLine(String.Format(provider, $"Choosen date is: {date:d}"));
```

This displays the date in my local format:
*Choosen date is: 22.04.2013*

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgBgARwIwG4CwAoRLUB0A4gDYD2ARgIYkCWAXlcLWVFrgMz4BsKATPgDsSAN44kElFzS84AFiQBZKrSgAKAJSjxk3QBEmAUwAqtALaGkAEyNIAvEiiGA7kgPAT5w2r4JUHABokOSC+Pg12XV0AMTIwMyZgKgoSQwBlYDBVAHMkADMAZ3skABIAIhsPYpFKwwBfMsioiTQATjVCgmMyDKyobLUAYQgSYAgwQwBJKDyyYkNgYdHxqZmyNTLDKABaAFU0so0jpua2joKunsycoZGxienZ+cW7lcf1zZ2iACFD450JHUcHUgA===

Comment: Interpolated strings have an implicit conversion to FormattableString, which allows formatting with different cultures. For an example see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring.invariant?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [FormattableString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring?view=netframework-4.8).

```
Console.WriteLine(
    ((FormattableString)$"Choosen date is: {date:d}")
      .ToString(provider)
);
```

[Tor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55674956/2055187) is simpler than this, unless you have multiple variables in interpolation string. FormattableString allows do multiple formats all in one shot.

here is a C# 10's way, from [aepot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12888024/aepot) below.

```
string.Create(provider, $"Choosen date is: {date:d}")
```

Comment: Or [C# 10](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/string-interpolation-in-c-10-and-net-6/) `string.Create(provider, $"Choosen date is: {date:d}");`

Answer (score 8):

You can just do: `Console.WriteLine($"Choosen date is: {date.ToString("d", provider)}"));`

Just format the date the same way as the string format inside the square brackets .