# String to Double in same .add Exception issue

Tags: vb.net

```
 Private Sub btnprocess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnprocess.Click
    Dim FullName As String = txtfullname.Text
    Dim comma As Integer = FullName.IndexOf(",")
    Dim Lname As String = FullName.Substring(0, comma)
    Dim Fname As String = FullName.Substring(comma + 2)
    Dim Lfirst As String = Lname.Substring(0, 1)
    Dim Ffirst As String = Fname.Substring(0, 1)
    Dim CSZ As String = txtlocation.Text
    Dim FourthC As String = CSZ.Length() - 4
    Dim zipfour As String = CSZ.Substring(FourthC)
    Dim strAdress As String
    Dim decchairs As Decimal
    Dim decsofas As Decimal
    decchairs = CDec(txtchairs.Text)
    decsofas = CDec(txtsofas.Text)
    Dim decPrice As Decimal = (decsofas * 925) + (decchairs * 350)


    strAdress = CStr(txtadress.Text)
    strAdress = CStr(txtadress.Text)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Invoice Number:" + Ffirst + Lfirst + FourthC)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Name:" + Fname + Lname)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Adress:" + strAdress)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("City:" + CSZ)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Number of Chairs:" + decchairs)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Number of Sofas:" + decsofas)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Number of Chairs:" + decchairs)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Price:" + decPrice)
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Sales Tax:" + (decPrice * 0.05))
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Total Price:" + decPrice + (decPrice * 0.05))
  End Sub
```

Trying to add both a String and Double in same .Add statement and it's giving me an exception saying 'Conversion from string "Number of Chairs:" to type 'Double' is not valid.'

What is the issue here that I'm not realizing ? Thank You.

Comment: What is the point of converting a `String` to a `String`, especially twice, as you do with `strAdress = CStr(txtadress.Text)`? That tends to suggest that you're not really thinking about data types very well. VB can be very forgiving with data types and that means that you can get away with not thinking about them too hard, but it also means that you can make mistakes and then not know why your results are not what you expect.

Comment: It's a bad idea to add items to a control one at a time unless there's a break between them. In your case, you should add all the items to a list of some sort first - an array, if you know the length, or a collection - and then add them to the control in one go with a single call to `AddRange`.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you're using the addition operator to perform concatenation. Use the concatenation operator. When both operands are type `String`, addition does map to concatenation, so the result is the same. When one operand is not a `String` though, it often doesn't. If one operand is a number, the system will attempt to convert the `String` operand to a number as well and add them. Your `String` is obviously not numeric so it fails. If you use the actual operator for the operation you want to perform, the system will convert the other operands to type `String` and concatenate them.

```vb
ListBox1.Items.Add("Invoice Number:" & Ffirst & Lfirst & FourthC)
ListBox1.Items.Add("Name:" & Fname & Lname)
ListBox1.Items.Add("Adress:" & strAdress)
ListBox1.Items.Add("City:" & CSZ)
ListBox1.Items.Add("Number of Chairs:" & decchairs)
ListBox1.Items.Add("Number of Sofas:" & decsofas)
ListBox1.Items.Add("Number of Chairs:" & decchairs)
ListBox1.Items.Add("Price:" & decPrice)
ListBox1.Items.Add("Sales Tax:" & (decPrice * 0.05))
ListBox1.Items.Add("Total Price:" & (decPrice + (decPrice * 0.05)))
```

Always use concatenation operators when you want to concatenate and addition operators only when you want to add.

That said, I rarely use concatenation operators at all anyway. Even when there would be only one, I tend to find string interpolation more readable:

```vb
ListBox1.Items.Add($"Invoice Number:{Ffirst}{Lfirst}{FourthC}")
ListBox1.Items.Add($"Name:{Fname}{Lname}")
ListBox1.Items.Add($"Adress:{strAdress}")
'...
```

Comment: Also, [How to use string interpolation with CultureInfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55674609/how-to-use-string-interpolation-with-cultureinfo) is useful in some circumstances.